# What is the energy of a vector field?

Tags: energy, variational-calculus

At first I want to say that I'm not an expert at all in maths and physics. I'm trying to understand an equation I've seen. They have a motion  field $u$, ie a function from $\mathbf{R}²$ to $\mathbf{R}²$. Then they define the following energy minimization problem:
$E(\widetilde{u}) = \int_{\Omega}|\nabla \widetilde{u}|²dx$. It's really close to the membrane problem (https://doc.freefem.org/tutorials/membrane.html), except $\widetilde{u} $ is a function from $\mathbf{R}²$ to $\mathbf{R}²$ instead of $\mathbf{R}²$ to $\mathbf{R}$. And then they say the solution is given by the Poisson equation $\Delta \widetilde{u}=0$.

There are two things I don't get:

1. Where does this energy minimization comes from ? I couldnt find a similar example elsewhere
2. How could $\Delta \widetilde{u}=0$ be correct ? 0 whould be replace by a null vector ? I mean the laplacian operator applied on a vector gives a vector as a result.

If you have any ideas about that, don't hesitate

Mordokkai

Comment: They are using the vector laplacian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but in this case it should be a null vector instead of 0 at my question 2. And do you see any other example where such a formula is used ? (cf question 1)

Comment: Surely no-one ever distinguishes between  ${\bf 0}$ and  $0$ in general writing?  I only do so when in there is a potential for confusion, and there is none here.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. For me it was confusing anyway :)